# requestAnimationFrame not supported in this Worker

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe, off-screen

I'm continuing with my canvas hobby a-a-and hit another problem while trying to offload most of the things with web workers. This is the current design:
[creating and starting the core web worker core.js from index.html]

```
  var canvas = document.getElementById('testcanvas');
  canvas.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  const offscreenCanvas = canvas.transferControlToOffscreen();

  const core = new Worker('core.js');

  //transfer offscreenCanvas just ONCE or will get a 'An OffscreenCanvas could not be cloned because it was detached' error
  core.postMessage({canvas: offscreenCanvas, msg: 'start'}, [offscreenCanvas]);
```

[in the core.js I'm creating two web workers]

```
'use strict'; //meh

const render = new Worker('render.js');

const mainloop = new Worker('mainloop.js');

onmessage = function(ev) {
  if (ev.data.msg === 'start') {
    mainloop.postMessage({msg: 'start'});
  }

  if (ev.data.canvas) {
    render.postMessage({canvas: ev.data.canvas}, [ev.data.canvas]);
  }

  if (ev.data.posX && ev.data.posY) {
    render.postMessage({posX: ev.data.posX, posY: ev.data.posY});
  }
}
```

each web worker sends the results to the core worker
[mainloop.js]

```
'use strict';

var canvas;
var ctx;

var speed = 100;

var currentTime = 0; var timeDiff = 0; var lastTime = 0;
var timeProduct = 0; var dTime = 0; var timeScale = 1; var timeStep = 0.01;

var posX = 10; var posY = 10;

function main() {
  currentTime = performance.now();
  timeDiff = (Math.abs(currentTime - lastTime) * 0.001);
  dTime += Math.min(timeDiff, 1);
  timeProduct = timeStep * timeScale;

  while (dTime > timeProduct) {
    postMessage({posX: posX, posY: posY});
    dTime -= timeProduct;
  }

  lastTime = currentTime;

  posX += speed * timeDiff;
  posY += speed * timeDiff;

  if (posX > 500) posX = 10;
  if (posY > 500) posY = 10;

  requestAnimationFrame(main);
  //setTimeout(main, 0);
}

onmessage = function(ev) {
  if(ev.data.msg === 'start') {
    main();
  }
}
```

[render.js]

```
'use strict';

var canvas;
var ctx;

function draw(posX, posY) {
  //clear
  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  //draw
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.moveTo(posX, posY);
  ctx.ellipse(posX,
              posY,
              5,
              5,
              0.7854,
              0,
              2 * Math.PI,
              false);
  ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
  ctx.stroke();
}

onmessage = function(ev) {
  if(ev.data) {
    if (!canvas) canvas = ev.data.canvas;
    if (!ctx) ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    draw(ev.data.posX, ev.data.posY);
  }
}
```

The problem is that when `requestAnimationFrame(main)` is called in the mainloop.js I'm receiving 'requestAnimationFrame not supported in this Worker' though `offscreenCanvas` has been transfered between core and render workers. When changed with `setTimeout(main, 0)` error disappears but nothing is drawn on the canvas ...

Comment: see [documention™](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Functions_and_classes_available_to_workers) for what is/is not available in a Worker

Comment: Ok, it seems creating a web workers inside a web worker is supported by Chrome (my current browser) and Firefox. In fact FF latest dev edition gives `'canvas.transferControlToOffscreen is not a function'` error

Comment: a worker created by a worker would still not be able to use requestAnimationFrame if requestAnimationFrame is not available to workers

Comment: That's why I tried with `setTimout` as fallback and as I said without a success

Comment: have you read the documentation for offscreencanvas? for Firefox, you need to enable it in about:config

Comment: From what I can see, `requestAnimationFrame` is only available in Chrome workers, `offScreenCanvas` is only available in Firefox if enabled in about:config, and the only rendering context available in `offScreenCanvas` seems to be `webgl` - so, trying to use rendering context `2d` in a worker appears doomed

Comment: Seems you're right ... After enabling it FF said `NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED` for `getContext('2d')`. The only solution is to return to workers created directly in the global scope. This is hilarious and crazy

Comment: @JaromandaX Any ideas how to overcome this without returning the workers in the main thread and without `webgl` context??

Comment: it's only render.js you'd move to the "main thread"

Comment: Firefox added support for requestAnimationFrame and cancelAnimationFrame in workers in v97, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1738971#c17